# Get __name__ of calling function's module in Python

Tags: python, stack-trace, introspection

Suppose `myapp/foo.py` contains:

```
def info(msg):
    caller_name = ????
    print '[%s] %s' % (caller_name, msg)
```

And `myapp/bar.py` contains:

```
import foo
foo.info('Hello') # => [myapp.bar] Hello
```

I want `caller_name` to be set to the `__name__` attribute of the calling functions' module (which is 'myapp.foo') in this case. How can this be done?

Comment: Assume that some other entry point script invokes bar.py .. and thus `caller_name` cannot be `__main__`

Answer (score 173, accepted):

Check out the inspect module:

`inspect.stack()` will return the stack information.

Inside a function, `inspect.stack()[1]` will return your caller's stack.  From there, you can get more information about the caller's function name, module, etc.

See the docs for details:

http://docs.python.org/library/inspect.html

Also, Doug Hellmann has a nice writeup of the inspect module in his PyMOTW series:

http://pymotw.com/2/inspect/index.html#module-inspect

EDIT: Here's some code which does what you want, I think:

```
import inspect 

def info(msg):
    frm = inspect.stack()[1]
    mod = inspect.getmodule(frm[0])
    print '[%s] %s' % (mod.__name__, msg)
```

Comment: So how do you get the `__name__` attribute of this module using the `inspect` module? For example, how do I get back `myapp.foo` (not `myapp/foo.py`) in my above example? I already tried using the inspect module before posting at SO.

Comment: Be aware that this will interact strangely with import hooks, won't work on ironpython, and may behave in surprising ways on jython.  It's best if you can avoid magic like this.

Comment: Also note that keeping a reference to a stack frame can prevent Python's GC from working correctly. See warning here: http://docs.python.org/library/inspect.html#the-interpreter-stack

Comment: Note that if the caller function is decorated (@...), you need to access `inspect.stack()[2]` for the real caller.

Comment: Also note that this logic fails to work properly when you compile your python code into an exe using pyinstaller.

Comment: I found this did not work when I was running my python code inside eggs

Comment: This does not seem to work with lambdas whose name have been set (for instance `f = lambda x: x; f.__name__ = 'my_function'`, can anyone confirm?

Comment: Seems like if have a breakpoint using something like `import ipdb; ipdb.set_trace()`, the location is at the `11th` place, not the `1st`.

Comment: @AmirAliAkbari Not so. Assuming that the decorator works by calling the original function, `inspect.stack()[1]` refers to the original function; `inspect.stack()[2]` refers to *the decorator*. Since the decorator is doing the calling, it will be lower down on the stack. It can't be above, anyway, because the original function code doesn't know about the decorator.

Comment: You *would* have the problem if you wanted to *use the decorator to call `info` on the decorated function's behalf*, though.

Answer (score 31):

Confronted with a similar problem, I have found that **sys._current_frames()** from the sys module contains interesting information that can help you, without the need to import inspect, at least in specific use cases.

```
>>> sys._current_frames()
{4052: <frame object at 0x03200C98>}
```

You can then "move up" using f_back :

```
>>> f = sys._current_frames().values()[0]
>>> # for python3: f = list(sys._current_frames().values())[0]

>>> print f.f_back.f_globals['__file__']
'/base/data/home/apps/apricot/1.6456165165151/caller.py'

>>> print f.f_back.f_globals['__name__']
'__main__'
```

For the filename you can also use f.f_back.f_code.co_filename, as suggested by Mark Roddy above. I am not sure of the limits and caveats of this method (multiple threads will most likely be a problem) but I intend to use it in my case.

Comment: note: the inspect.stack code FAILS after compile to exe using pyinstaller, but using sys._current_frames WORKS FINE... so this is the preferred technique for me.

Comment: I think it's easier to get the previous frame by [`sys._getframe(1)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys._getframe), instead of calling `sys._current_frames()` (btw which returns a frame mapping for every thread).

Comment: Thank you hooblei, I haven't tested it yet but seems very useful for multi-threaded situations.

Comment: I prefer to use [`inspect.currentframe()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#inspect.currentframe) instead of `sys._current_frames().values()[0]`.

Answer (score 8):

I don't recommend do this, but you can accomplish your goal with the following method:

```
def caller_name():
    frame=inspect.currentframe()
    frame=frame.f_back.f_back
    code=frame.f_code
    return code.co_filename
```

Then update your existing method as follows:

```
def info(msg):
    caller = caller_name()
    print '[%s] %s' % (caller, msg)
```

Comment: Filename is not the same as `__name__`

Answer (score 5):

As for me, following line was enough to get callers'name.

```
import inspect
frame = inspect.stack()[-1]
print(frame.filename)
```