# Importing Modules that use MultiProcessing Python

Tags: python, import, matrix, parallel-processing, multiprocessing

I am looking to use the multiprocessing module to speed up the run time of some Transport Planning models.  I've optimized as much as I can via 'normal' methods but at the heart of it is an absurdly parallel problem. Eg Perform the same set of matrix operations four 4 different sets of inputs, all independent information.

Pseudo Code:

```
    for mat1,mat2,mat3,mat4 in zip([a1,a2,a3,a4],[b1,b2,b3,b4],[c1,c2,c3,c4],[d1,d2,d3,d4]):
        result1 = mat1*mat2^mat3
        result2 = mat1/mat4
        result3 = mat3.T*mat2.T+mat4
```

So all I really want to do is process the iterations of this loop in parallel on a quad core computer.  I've read up here and other places on the multiprocessing module and it seems to fit the bill perfectly except for the required:

```
   if __name__ == '__main__'
```

From what I understand this means that you can only multiprocess code run from a script?  ie if I do something like:

```
    import multiprocessing
    from numpy.random import randn

    a = randn(100,100)
    b = randn(100,100)
    c = randn(100,100)
    d = randn(100,100)

    def process_matrix(mat):
        return mat^2

    if __name__=='__main__':
        print "Multiprocessing"
        jobs=[]

        for input_matrix in [a,b,c,d]:
            p = multiprocessing.Process(target=process_matrix,args=(input_matrix,))
            jobs.append(p)
            p.start()
```

It runs fine, however assuming I saved the above as 'matrix_multiproc.py', and defined a new file 'importing_test.py' which just states:

```
    import matrix_multiproc
```

The multiprocessing does not happen because the name is now 'matrix_multiproc' and not '**main**'

Does this mean I can never use parallel processing on an imported module? All I am trying to do is have my model run as:

```
    def Model_Run():
        import Part1, Part2, Part3, matrix_multiproc, Part4

        Part1.Run()
        Part2.Run()
        Part3.Run()
        matrix_multiproc.Run()
        Part4.Run()
```

Sorry for a really long question to what is probably a simple answer, thanks!

Answer (score 13):

> Does this mean I can never use parallel processing on an imported module?

No, it doesn't.  You can use `multiprocessing` anywhere in your code, *provided* that the program's main module uses the `if __name__ == '__main__'` guard.

On Unix systems, you won't even need that guard, since it features the `fork()` system call to create child processes from the main `python` process.

On Windows, on the other hand, `fork()`  is emulated by `multiprocessing` by spawning a new process that runs the main module *again*, using a different `__name__`.  Without the guard here, your main application will try to spawn new processes again, resulting in an endless loop, and eating up all your computer's memory pretty fast.

Comment: Does that mean I shouldn't see the big old warning on Unix systems?  Or is there still a spurious warning?  I'm seeing it on OSX.

Comment: @dylanyoung that's because osx [uses spawn by default](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html?highlight=pool#contexts-and-start-methods) since python 3.something.  This is due to a [bug with fork](https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/77906) in recent versions of macos.

Answer (score 1):

> You can use multiprocessing anywhere in your code, provided that the program's main module uses the `if __name__ == '__main__'` guard.

That's not the best way.  The `__main__` test is overly restrictive, it doesn't work in module code and limits what you can do.  And it's not necessary.  Any test that executes the initializing code exactly once across processes will do the job.

### Better way

A better solution is to test for an environment variable.  If it's unset, then set it and initialize your multiprocessing.  Spawned processes will inherit environ changes, see variable is already set, and not create more processes.

A more complex way is to inspect all parent frames for the name `__main__`.  This way is harder and more error prone.  KISS.

Rest of this post explains why these approaches are better.

### Example

For instance, say you want to start a listener process in an imported module.  Listener will monitor a Queue for data and handle it (in this example, log it).  Notionally we have this:

```
# ----- in module.py
def listener (queue) :
    while true :
        ... # do something with queue

def init () :
    'setup shared queue and start listener process'
    manager = mp.get_manager ()
    queue = mp.Queue ()

    child = manager.Process (
       target = listener,
       args = queue,
       daemon = true   # so parent process doesn't hang waiting for child
    )
    child.start ()

# start the listener
init ()

def log (msg) :
    queue.put (msg)


# ----- in main.py
import module

log ('foo')
```

The above code is fine with fork, but breaks with spawn.  init () will run again in the child, spawning another child, and another, ...

How can you fix?  You can't test for `__name__ == '__main__'` when module.py is imported.  `__name__` will be module.  So that doesn't work.

Here's the obvious (and bad) solution: you could move init () call to main.py and wrap it in `__name__ == '__main__'`.  This is bad.  Now anyone importing module.py has to call module.init () before they can use it.  Imagine if stdlib worked like this.  You might have to call 15 or 20 init funcs before you could start doing anything, and it's easy to miss one.  Too error prone.

### Module chains

The obvious solution also breaks when another module includes your module.  Consider this scenario:

```
# --- mod1.py

def init () : ...  # start a child listener process
def log (msg) : ...

# --- mod2.py

import mod1.py

def somefunc (*args) :
    do something...
    mod1.log (f'result is : { result }')

if __name__ == '__main__' :
   mod1.init ()

# --- main.py

import mod2

mod2.somefunc ()
```

Now main.py breaks.  mod1.init () was never called.  main.py doesn't even import mod1.  The init problem is worse than before.  Testing for `__main__` is a bad solution.

### Better way : use os.environ

A better solution is to test for an environment variable.  If it's not set, then this is first pass.  Set the variable and init your processes.  Spawned children will inherit environ, see it's already set, and not init again.  This keeps all the init behavior where it belongs, inside the module.

The challenge with this method is making sure you pick a unique env var name that isn't used by other programs on the system or by other python modules.  I recommend using `__file__` because that doesnt change, unlike `__name__`.  To be really safe, use the full path.

In first example above, replace call to `init ()` with the following:

```
# --- module.py

envkey = 'PYSPAWN_' + os.path.basename (__file__)

# start the listener on first pass (parent process)
if not os.environ.get (envkey, false) :

    os.environ [envkey] = str (os.getpid ())
    init ()
```

If you just use `__name__` instead of `__file__`, it will still work when module.py is imported.  However, when module.py is run as the main script, name will be `__main__` on first run, then `main` or `mpmain` or similar in spawned children (depends on multiprocessing lib you use).  `envkey` will have two different values and you'll get an extra child process.

### Other options

You could also test for the name `__main__` by looking at all parent frames [as described here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5071539/7663296).  Have to look through entire stack though, as caller may not be the main module, like in second example above.  Not as simple and efficient as using environ.  Simpler solution is better.