# Parallel processing in python and need for if __name__ == '__main__'

Tags: python, multiprocessing, subprocess, gil

I've been battling the **need for parallel processing** in my application. I have relatively good understanding that GIL prevents concurrent processing in a single interpreter, and that there can only be one interpreter per process. At least until [3.10](https://peps.python.org/pep-0554/) (I need to use 3.8 to integrate manufacturer's drivers). But my application is proving challenging.

#### My application requirements:

In my application we I'm creating an **image acquisition module** that will handle an arbitrary number of Flir cameras connected to a computer, for robotics and machine vision. This means the image acquisition module will run in parallel with other modules that control important things, such as motors and DAQs.

When initialized, the image acquisition module will check all cameras in the system to see which one has the name requested:

```py
import ImageAcquisition as ia

ia.Initialize("cam1", "cam2") # Creates two parallel process. One for each camera.
```

For each camera a parallel process should be created to handle the image analysis associated with it. This means grabbing frames, displaying them, processing them, and also making some image analysis results available to the main process.

One important requirement is the module is self-contained. However, I'm finding that the `if __name__ == "__main__":` test is always needed in the program entry code (client code). This is because the new processes will run the main program on their interpreters as well.

**Is there an alternative to having `if __name__ == "__main__":`?** So I can make my module fully self-contained.

One alternative could be to use the subprocess library and run the process without the "spawn" mechanism that is used by multiprocessing library in Windows. But there is some overhead when it comes to sharing information between processes that is better handled in the multiprocessing library.

Another alternative is to inject the `if __name__ == "__main__":` in the user's strings, in our main application.

Comment: Do the answers to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7989123/importing-modules-that-use-multiprocessing-python) help at all?

Comment: Platforms that use the spawn method to create new processes: (1) You don't put `if __name__ == "__main__":` in a module that is being imported because `__name__` will not be "\_\_main__" in an imported module. (2) You should have no code in an imported module that is at global scope and creates new processes directly or indirectly. (3) There is always some script file that gets executed initially. If that script contains any code at global scope that results directly or indirectly in the creation of new processes, then that main script code must be within an `if __name__ == "__main__"` block.

Comment: @quamrana Thank you for the link. That post addresses guarding the module initialization code from running on the child processes, using an OS env variable. However, in my application the client should not rerun just because they imported my module. The client code will move motors and initialize hardware and that could be dangerous also.
@Booboo I'm aware __name__ will only be '__main__' in the main code and not the module. I meant that the `if` guard needs to be in the client code.
Thanks for the help and let me know if you need more clarification on the question.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that I understood you correctly. But it seems I had a similar problem a while ago. One solution to bypass `if __name__` was to do a nested import. The function I wanted to run via multiprocessing was hidden in a second module that was imported into my main module.

See this solution here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/29751273/4141279

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following:

```py
import os

_env_variable = f'{__name__}-multiprocessing'
if os.environ.get(_env_variable) is None:
    os.environ[_env_variable] = True  # Child process will not now execute following code

    # Create the processes:
    import ImageAcquisition as ia
```

On platforms that use the *spawn* method of creating child processes, the above code will create the child processes when the module is initially imported but will set an environment variable inherited by child processes that will prevent the same code from being executed in the child process.