# Writing a small function inside a class method[Python]

Tags: python, function, coding-style, definition

If I have a script like:

```
class ClassA(object):
    ...
    def methodA(...):
        varA=...

        def funcA(...):
            ...

        varA=funA(...)
```

I mean I intend to write a small function inside a class method, which is only used inside this class method. Is this code style OK? I think it's a little ugly. Is there alternate?

Comment: One potential problem is that you'll be re-defining `funcA` every time `methodA` is called.

Comment: Have you considered using a lambda function instead?

Comment: @Blender then how can I avoid re-defining funcA?

Comment: @ThunderEX: By defining it outside of `methodA`.

Comment: Why are you doing it this way?  Do you have a reason for putting funcA inside `methodA` instead of elsewhere (or just doing its operations directly in the body of `methodA`)?

Comment: @BrenBarn because in this way it seems clearer that funA only works for methodA

Comment: @ThunderEX: But then what is the point of making it a function?  Why not just put its contents directly into `methodA`?

Comment: @BrenBarn Because that piece of code is frequently used in the method

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13984818/limit-a-method-to-be-called-only-through-another-method/13984872#13984872) from just an hour ago for some discussion.

Comment: @BrenBarn nice! i am going to keep its original style now.

Comment: @ThunderEX, I would only do this if the function really does need to be nested, e.g. if it accesses some variables from the scope of the enclosing method, or if you need different defaults each time (though `partial` may be preferable in the second instance). However, in that situation it is perfectly fine. Don't worry about redefining the function every time the method is called: function definitions are no more expensive than any other object creation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Beauty is in the eye of the beholder.

It is totally fine having a very "local" function nested inside another function - especially from the point of readability of code.

Others will argue with coding style and best practice.

It is your code and you must feel fine with your code in order to understand and read it later.

So if it is fine for you and your understanding of "nice" code, go ahead.