# How to get the nested function objects?

Tags: python

```
def foo():
    print "I am foo"
    def bar1():
       print "I am bar1"
    def bar2():
       print "I am bar2"
    def barN():
       print "I am barN"


funobjs_in_foo = get_nest_functions(foo)

def get_nest_functions(funobj):
    #how to write this function??
```

How to get all the nested function objects? I can get the code object of the nesting functions through funobj.func_code.co_consts. But I haven't found a way to get the function objects for the nested functions.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: check this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1095543/get-name-of-calling-functions-module-in-python

Comment: Thanks. The inspect frame only hold the code objects. Somebody proposed a way to get function object from code object by using gc. But it doesn't work for this nested function scenario.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you noticed, `foo.func_code.co_consts` only contains the code objects, not function objects.

You can't get the function objects simply because they don't exist. They are recreated whenever the function is called (and only the code objects are re-used).

Confirm that using:

```
>>> def foo():
...     def bar():
...         print 'i am bar'
...     return bar
....
>>> b1 = foo()
>>> b2 = foo()
>>> b1 is b2
False
>>> b1.func_code is b2.func_code
True
```