# Logger module wants to know the path of the module that initialized it

Tags: python, logging

I have a custom logger defined in

**/utils/my_logger.py**

```
class MyLogger():
    def __init__(self, name, path_of_module):
        self.logger_name = name
        self.path = path_of_module

    def get_logger(self):
        ...
        #setLevel, formatter, handler, etc.
        return logger
```

say, in another file somewhere I import and instantiate MyLogger..

**/some/path/to/foo.py**

```
handler = MyLogger("testing", os.path.realpath(__file__))
log = handler.get_logger()
```

Is there any way to do this so that I don't have to explicitly write `os.path.realpath(__file__)` as an argument every time I instantiate the logger?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the inspect module to look for the caller on the stack. From there, you can get the caller's module and `__file__`. Look at [Get **name** of calling function's module in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1095543/get-name-of-calling-functions-module-in-python) - its getting module name but the same goes for the file name.

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
import inspect
os.path.abspath(inspect.stack()[-1][1])
```

Answer (score 0):

[Edit]: changed to os.getcwd()
Do it in the **init** method,

```
def __init__(self, name):
        self.logger_name = name
        self.path = os.getcwd()
```

Isn't that better ?!

Comment: That gets the module the class is defined in, not the module that instantiates the class.