# Get relative path of caller in Python

Tags: python, path

I've got this function:

```
def relative_path(*paths):
    return os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), *paths)
```

How would I change it to return the path **relative to the *caller?***

For example, if I called `relative_path('index.html')` from another script, is it possible to get the path relative the script from where it was called implicitly or would I need to modify `relative_path` to pass `__file__` across as well like this?

```
def relative_path(__file__, *paths):
    return os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), *paths)
```

Comment: do these paths strictly begin with the directory of the caller?

Comment: Are you asking how to determine the path of the script the caller resides within? If not, what is the path of the caller?

Comment: I don't know how to make it more clear than "Get relative path of caller". Could you clarify why that is not clear?

Comment: Why the need to magically use the parent file location? Why not be more explicit about what to base the path on? Flask requires you to create the `Flask()` object with the current module name (`app = Flask(__name__)`) so that it can look up the path to load templates (`sys.modules[name_passed_in].__file__`). That makes it explicit and also lets you override the path. No magic caller lookups required.

Answer (score 3):

adapting the solution in [Get __name__ of calling function's module in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1095543/get-name-of-calling-functions-module-in-python)

file1.py

```
import os
import inspect

def relative_path(*paths):
    return os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), *paths)

def relative_to_caller(*paths):
    frm = inspect.stack()[1]
    mod = inspect.getmodule(frm[0])
    return os.path.join(os.path.dirname(mod.__file__), *paths)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(relative_path('index.html'))
```

sub/sub_file.py

```
import sys
sys.path.append(r'/Users/xx/PythonScripts/!scratch')

import file1

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(file1.relative_path('index.html'))
    print(file1.relative_to_caller('index.html'))
```

Running sub_file.py gives the following output:

```
/Users/xx/PythonScripts/!scratch/index.html
/Users/xx/PythonScripts/!scratch/sub/index.html
```

There are some caveats in the comments to the question in the link above...

Answer (score 0):

Note that tracing stack would be a possibility here, but it could cause some serious trouble ( like confusing 'garbage collector', or may not even work in eggs )

I believe the cleanest way would be to pass the caller to the rel_path function.

However, as you may know, there is usually an ugly way of doing things in python. You can do for example something like this:

consider following two scripts:

```
# relpath.py

import os


def rel_path(path):
    if os.path.isfile(__name__):
        return os.path.relpath(path, start=__name__)

    print("Warning: %s is not a file: returning path relative to the current working dir" % __name__, file=sys.stderr)
    return os.path.relpath(path)
```

```
# caller.py

import importlib.util


spec = importlib.util.spec_from_file_location(name=__file__, location="/workspace/relpath.py")

rel =  importlib.util.module_from_spec(spec)

spec.loader.exec_module(rel)
print(rel.rel_path("/tmp"))
```

What we did here: when loading the module using importlib.util, we passed the `name=__file__`, which gave our module the name consisting of the caller script *path*. Hence we needn't pass it as an argument to the *relpath.py*.

Note that this is **not** clean solution and might not be *readable* for future developers reading your code. I just wanted to demonstrate the possibilities of python.