# See what Python module instantised a class?

Tags: python

Is it possible in a Python class to see the name (or other identifier) of the class or module that instantises it?

For example:

```
# mymodule.py

class MyClass():
    def __init__(self):
        print(instantised_by)

#main.py

from mymodule import MyClass

instance = MyClass()
```

Running `main.py` should print:

```
main
```

or something like that.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can inspect the stack informations with `inspect` to get the caller stack from `__init__` (remember, it's just a function). From that you can get informations such as the caller function name, module name etc.

See this question: [Get __name__ of calling function's module in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1095543/get-name-of-calling-functions-module-in-python).

Answer (score 0):

With `traceback` module:

```
import traceback

class MyClass():
    def __init__(self):
       file,line,w1,w2 = traceback.extract_stack()[1]
       print(w1)
```

Comment: this will print `__init__`

Comment: nope, it prints `main` when running from `main.py`. Test it you'll see.